# Connection String of ms access database 2010 in c# for dns less

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

Friends...
 Since,

```
 OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
 Data Source=C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\db.accdb");
```

This string use in c# for ms access database connection..see database location already known and it works..

But, I want to run application when database in any location ...(i.e) it should take database location Automatically from any location( when user save project in any location)

Can some buddy help me..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating the logic in C# to *determine* where the DB is. Once you know, it's as simple as string concatenation:

```
var dbLocation = GetDbLocation();
OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                              Data Source=" + dbLocation ");
```

`GetDbLocation()` could pull the information from a config file, or determine it in some other way (you haven't given us enough information to determine where the DB is located).

Answer (score 0):

Copy your database to App_Data

and use this code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") + "\\" + "db.accdb";

OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                               Data Source="+path +"");
```

Hope This Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, it will help you...

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            path = path + "\\db.accdb";
            OleDbConnection vcon = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path);
```

Place the EXE of your app and DB in the Same Location and use the Above Code...

If you place database in the folder Database then try like below...

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            path = path + "\\DataBase\\db.accdb";
            OleDbConnection vcon = new 
OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide db location, through the connectionstring. There's no other way for OleDbConnection to know the location of database file.

Now, what you can do is it specify your connection string at runtime in either of these ways.

1. have collection of connectionstrings at your disposal, all of them pointing to predetermined locations, specify/choose one of them dynamically. i.e.

   ```
       OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
       cn.ConnectionString = variable;
   ```
2. simple string concatenation of a single connection string.

Either way, you have to determine the location prehand. There's no magic code, which would search your entire system for `.accdb` file on auto and plug it in. Even if you write such a code, that would be  a broken code or superbly specific code anyway.

So its better to manage your connectionStrings (all possible pre-determined locations, where you have put (copies of) your db file) in the web.config.

Or, you can create a db table to store all possible connectionstrings, to which you can add entries and delete entries, through a simple user interface.